# Procedure for Altering Table and updating keeps failing with invalid column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, alter-table

I'm trying to add new columns to a table then update the table and set the new column with a date format change of the old column.

I have my procedure set out as follows:

```
begin
alter table [dbo].[mytable]
add New_Field1 varchar(24)
end

......

update [dbo].[SMR06_TARGET]
set New_Field1 = convert(varchar(24),Old_Field1,103)

.....
```

I have multiple alter table statements at the top of the table and update statements at the bottom for each new column. I think this is a rule with SQL keeping DDL at top and DML at bottom.

Ok so everytime I execute this to create the procedure it fails with incorrect column name New_Field1. I really can't peg down what is causing this. I've tried different variations of BEGIN....END tried commenting out the apprent offending statement, then it runs, then it fails again with the next statement.

I'm reckoning it's something to do with the way the statement(s) are terminated. I'm not sure as haven't done this type of procedure statement before with mixed DDL/DML.

Any hints would be most welcome.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: You need to separate these into batches. Use GO after your alter table statements (each).

Comment: Are you really trying to do this inside a stored procedure? If so, why? You won't be able to run it more than once.

Comment: You should not be adding extra fields in a different format. Keep the Old_Field1 in the datetime data type and when you want is to look different, just use your convert in your select statement. Like: select convert(varchar(24),Old_Field1,103) as New_Field1

Answer (score 1):

You need to batch the statement that adds the column separately from the statement that updates it.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable]
ADD New_Field1 varchar(24) NULL
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET New_Field1 = convert(varchar(24),Old_Field1,103)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Batch SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire batch is reviewed by the parser before it starts executing the first line.  Adding Old_Field1 is in the same batch as the reference to use Old_Field1.  At the time the parser considers the statement containing Old_Field1, the statement to add Old_Field1 has not been executed, so that field does not yet exist.

If you're running in SSMS, include GO between each statement to force multiple batches.  If you're running this in another tool that can't use GO, you'll need to submit each statement individually to ensure that they are fully executed before the next step is parsed.